# Date parsing issue with Arabic and regular date in Java

Tags: java, date

I have a date converter function like:

```
public static LocalDate getLocalDateFromString(String dateString) {
    DecimalStyle defaultDecimalStyle = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE.getDecimalStyle();
    DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE.withDecimalStyle(defaultDecimalStyle.withZeroDigit('\u0660'));
    LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(dateString, dateTimeFormatter);
    return date;
}
```

It works fine for Arabic dates like `٢٠١٩-٠٤-١٥`, but when I pass a normal date like `2019-07-31`, it throws an exception because the formatter is of a different type:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2019-07-31' could not be parsed at index 0
```

I don't have control over the date passed, as it is passed by the user.

How can I use the same function to parse both dates?

Comment: One (not too elegant) way is to attempt to parse in both ways. This is only reliable provided that you are sure there would not be any possible `dateString` that can be successfully parsed by *both* methods.

Comment: The downside of @Jai comment is that you will need to add other parse method each time a new locale is introduced

Comment: Is the Arabic-Indic zero really needed for _parsing_? For _formating_ the output there sure is a Locale based possibility.

Comment: Yes, @JoopEggen, parsing fails with an exception if the (zero) digit setting of the formatter and the digits in the string don’t agree. And yes, if you know the user’s locale, you can use `DecimalStyle.of` to get the decimal style for that locale, and you’re done, also for input/parsing.

Comment: @OleV.V. thanks, and nice trick in for identifying the zero digit of a script.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Know your string

`DateTimeFormatter` doesn’t make this very easy for you. I am speculating that there may be a purpose behind this choice: it’s better if you can bring yourself into a situation where you know beforehand what kind of digits is used in the string you are going to parse. You may give this a thought: could you persuade the source of your string to pass this information to you?

### Take a taste and act accordingly

If not, of course there is a way through. The following is low-level but should be general.

```
public static LocalDate getLocalDateFromString(String dateString) {
    DateTimeFormatter dateFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE;
    // Take a digit from dateString to determine which digits are used
    char sampleDigit = dateString.charAt(0);
    if (Character.isDigit(sampleDigit)) {
        // Subtract the numeric value of the digit to find the zero digit in the same digit block
        char zeroDigit = (char) (sampleDigit - Character.getNumericValue(sampleDigit));
        assert Character.isDigit(zeroDigit) : zeroDigit;
        assert Character.getNumericValue(zeroDigit) == 0 : zeroDigit;
        DecimalStyle defaultDecimalStyle = dateFormatter.getDecimalStyle();
        dateFormatter = dateFormatter
                .withDecimalStyle(defaultDecimalStyle.withZeroDigit(zeroDigit));
    }
    // If the examined char wasn’t a digit, the following parsing will fail;
    // but in that case the best we can give the caller is the exception from that failed parsing.
    LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(dateString, dateFormatter);
    return date;
}
```

Let’s try it out:

```
    System.out.println("Parsing Arabic date string to  "
            + getLocalDateFromString("٢٠١٩-٠٤-١٥"));
    System.out.println("Parsing Western date string to "
            + getLocalDateFromString("2019-07-31"));
```

Output from this snippet is:

> ```
> Parsing Arabic date string to  2019-04-15
> Parsing Western date string to 2019-07-31
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I think a better solution is to override the method in your class.

Comment: Thanks for wanting to contribute. I didn’t really get your suggestion, and I suspect that you may have misunderstood the asker’s situation. If not you may want to add some precision and explanation to your answer?

Answer (score 0):

## Two formatters

If you are expecting either of two formats in your incoming strings, establish two `DateTimeFormatter` objects, one for each expected format.

## Try both

Try one formatter, trapping for the `DateTimeParseException`. If thrown, try the other. If the second throws as well, then you know you’ve received unexpected faulty input.

If you have more than two expected formats, collect all the possible `DateTimeFormatter` objects. The loop the collection, try each to parse the input, until one does not throw the parsing exception.