# Converting a string with Arabic characters to a date

Tags: java, arabic, java-time, localdate, date-parsing

I'm trying to verify that a list of items are sorted according their date desc through Java and appium. I managed to extract the dates from the screen as a String, but I'm facing a difficulty in converting these strings into dates because the string is basically containing an Arabic date, like the following:
يناير ٧ ٢٠٢٠

I've tried to use the code below,

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu d MMMM ", new Locale("ar"));
        LocalDate orderDate = LocalDate.parse(date, formatter);
```

However, Im getting the following error:

```
java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text 'يناير ٧ ٢٠٢٠' could not be parsed at index 0

    at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(DateTimeFormatter.java:2046)
    at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1948)
    at java.base/java.time.LocalDate.parse(LocalDate.java:428)
    at com.hs.mobile.steps.MyOrdersSteps.getDate(MyOrdersSteps.java:142)
    at com.hs.mobile.steps.MyOrdersSteps.getOrdersDates(MyOrdersSteps.java:133)
    at com.hs.mobile.steps.MyOrdersSteps.verifyOrdersSortedByDateDesc(MyOrdersSteps.java:119)
    at com.hs.mobile.tests.MyOrdersTests.navigateToOrders_OrdersShouldBeSortedByDate(MyOrdersTests.java:30)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:133)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeMethod(TestInvoker.java:584)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethod(TestInvoker.java:172)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodRunner.runInSequence(MethodRunner.java:46)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker$MethodInvocationAgent.invoke(TestInvoker.java:804)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethods(TestInvoker.java:145)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:146)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:128)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1540)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:770)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:591)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:402)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.access$000(SuiteRunner.java:41)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner$SuiteWorker.run(SuiteRunner.java:443)
    at org.testng.internal.thread.ThreadUtil.lambda$execute$0(ThreadUtil.java:67)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run$$$capture(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

Can you please advise in a proper solution for this issue?

Thanks

Comment: Are you familiar with logical order and visual order? The first part of the date string appearing in your question is the name of the month, hence the first part of your pattern string must be MMMM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pls check out my solution, it is really very tricky to convert from ar to another locale because when you read from arabic you have to read text from the right to left like this:

```
the -> "يناير ٧ ٢٠٢٠" will be: january 7 2020
```

so DateFormatter will look like this:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf =
            new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM d yyyy", Locale.forLanguageTag("ar-SA-nu-arab"));
```

and then parse it to the date:

```
Date d = sdf.parse(date);
```

and print it:

```
        System.out.println(d);
```

it will print this:

```
Tue Jan 07 00:00:00 MSK 2020
```

Comment: Interesting... this pattern does not work in a `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMMM d yyyy")`, but it tells me *Text 'يناير ٧ ٢٠٢٠' could not be parsed at index 6* while putting the original pattern says *Text 'يناير ٧ ٢٠٢٠' could not be parsed at index 0*. That means you are (at least partially) right by pointing to the left-right difference. Have you parsed it with `java.time`? I think the problem is the character *٧* (it's the the 7, respectively the `d` in the pattern, I think).

Comment: This actually worked thanks. But what if I only want to use the language, regardless the country. Would that still work, is there another tag for only language?

Comment: Please don’t teach the young ones to use the long outdated and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class. At least not as the first option. And not without any reservation. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) and its `DateTimeFormatter`. This was even used in the question, it can do the job just fine, there’s absolutely no reason to use anything else here.

Comment: @deHaar `DateTimeFormatter` needs to be told explicitly to use Arab digits (like ٧) whereas the outdated `SimpleDateFormat` picks this up from the locale. I don’t know why there is this difference in design.

Comment: @OleV.V. Yes, I have seen that while searching for different approaches. It's obviously one of the few things that were easier to achieve with `java.util`...

Comment: @deHaar If you want to use the locale’s digits, yes. I find it perfectly realistic to imagine cases where one wants to use the month name from one locale and the digits from another one. It seems to me that `SimpleDateFormat` cannot do that while the modern `DateTimeFormatter` can.

Comment: @OleV.V. Sure, the mightier, the better... I couldn't get the parsing of the `String` from the question to work, do you know how to do it? Just out of interest and I think the accepted answer is ok for Java 4 and lower, but shouldn't be the only working one here.

Comment: @OleV.V. I think I have tried your code (found [on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55017576/date-parsing-issue-with-arabic-and-regular-date-in-java) and [on some Asian site](https://www.hellojava.com/a/64247.html), it is exactly your answer text ;-) ) but it didn't work with the same problem (`Text could not be parsed at index 0`).

Comment: @OleV.V. I bet I failed copy & pasting the arabic date `String` ;-)

Answer (score 4):

### Just stay with java.time and DateTimeFormatter

```
    char arabicZero = '\u0660';
    DateTimeFormatter dateFormatter = DateTimeFormatter
            .ofPattern("MMMM d uuuu", Locale.forLanguageTag("ar"));
    DecimalStyle arabicDecimalStyle
            = dateFormatter.getDecimalStyle().withZeroDigit(arabicZero);
    dateFormatter = dateFormatter.withDecimalStyle(arabicDecimalStyle);

    String dateString = "يناير ٧ ٢٠٢٠";

    LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(dateString, dateFormatter);
    System.out.println("Parsed date: " + date);
```

Output from this snippet is:

> Parsed date: 2020-01-07

In my most honest opinion you did right when trying to use `DateTimeFormatter` for the job.  This class is part of java.time, the modern Java date and time API. In contrast to the old and long outdated `SimpleDateFormat` it uses Western digits as default, so we need to tell it explicitly to use Arabic digits. As discussed in the comments this design allows us to construct formatters with any combination of month names from one culture and digits from another, both for formatting and for parsing.